# Tensorflow: How to test development code without building the whole library?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I've edited some bits of a local fork of tensorflow and now I want to test it. However, when I try importing tensoflow from python path I run into the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
>   "/home/alex/work/python/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/self_check.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.platform import build_info
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'build_info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/alex/work/python/double_nf_vae/bin/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf   File "/home/alex/work/python/tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *   File "/home/alex/work/python/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "/home/alex/work/python/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import self_check   File "/home/alex/work/python/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/self_check.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Could not import tensorflow. Do not import tensorflow " ImportError: Could not import tensorflow. Do not import tensorflow from its source directory; change directory to outside the TensorFlow source tree, and relaunch your Python interpreter from there.
```

Is there any workaround that at all?

Comment: What part of the code base have you edited? As the error message states, you cannot `import tensorflow` when your `PYTHONPATH` also contains a directory called `tensorflow` that contains an incomplete copy of the source tree (i.e. without generated files like `build_info`, protocol buffer wrappers, and the native library). If you are using Bazel, and only changing Python code, the incremental rebuild time should be pretty short.

Comment: Hm... so I'm outside tensorflows' source dir and importing it. What I think you might be suggesting is that if I have installed tensorflow, and also edited and added a second version of it, that is an issue?

Comment: Does the directory `/home/alex/work/python/tensorflow` contain a checkout of the TensorFlow git repository, or a complete build? I'm guessing it's the former, based on the stack trace and error message. If you also have an installed version somewhere else, Python isn't finding it, because the version in `/home/alex/work/python/tensorflow` is taking precedence, presumably due to how it interprets the (possibly implicit) `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Yes only a checkout of the repository. Would it be a solution to build at least once the repo tensorflow or will I need to build it every time?

Comment: If you are only modifying Python code for experimental purposes, one possibility would be to build the PIP package using Bazel, install it into a virtualenv, and then modify the installed version of the library (in `lib/site-packages/pythonX.X/tensorflow`).